# Micronaut Data: create and save new entity

Tags: jpa, kotlin, micronaut

I want to persist new entities during application startup as follows:

```
class Application(
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
) {
    @EventListener
    fun init(event: StartupEvent) {
        val encyclopedia = BookEntity(0, "The sublime source of knowledge")
        val notebook = BookEntity(0, "Release your creativity!")
        bookRepository.saveAll(listOf(encyclopedia, notebook))
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/snapshot/guide/#quickStart) this should work, but for some reason I get `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist` exception.

Comment: What is the first argument to your `BookEntity` constructor being used for?  Is it the `id`?

Comment: Yes, the first argument to the `BookEntity` constructor is the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed ID `0` to `BookEntity` constructor to indicate that it is a new entity. It works with JDBC, but when you are using JPA, `0` must be relaced with `null`. The following works as expected:

```
class Application(
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
) {
    @EventListener
    fun init(event: StartupEvent) {
        val encyclopedia = BookEntity(null, "The sublime source of knowledge")
        val notebook = BookEntity(null, "Release your creativity!")
        bookRepository.saveAll(listOf(encyclopedia, notebook))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that.  Why don't you just have a constructor in `BookEntity` that only accepts the `String` argument and leave the `id` out of the constructor altogether?